# Select submit button after form submit in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form id="save-form-datas">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I select my button to get the text `Submit` if I have the following JS code:

```
$('#save-form-datas').on('submit', function (e) {
    ...
}
```

I do not want to add id or class in my HTML code.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to get the `text` in `submit` button?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, I want to select my button to get the text `Submit`. Thanks.

Comment: @Maman do you mean multiple button within a same form ? and one of them is submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since its a `button` tag you should use `.html()` or `.text()` to get the text or html inside it rather than `.value()`

```js
$('.save-form-datas').on('submit', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).find('button').text());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="save-form-datas">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="save-form-datas">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <button type="submit">Submit2</button>
</form>
<form class="save-form-datas">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <button type="submit">Submit3</button>
</form>
<form class="save-form-datas">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <button type="submit">Submit4</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, but if I have more than one button, it will not work like expected. I need to track the submit button in the current form. Something like `$(this)...`?

Comment: updated the answer see if you are talking about the above scenario @Maman

Comment: Works. Note, that `.text()` makes the job too. Thanks.